# How is base.GetHashCode() implemented for a struct?

Tags: c#, struct, hashcode

I saw this code recently in a `struct` and I was wondering what `base.GetHashCode` actually does.

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hashCode = -592410294;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + base.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + m_Value.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coreclr repo has [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ffcb0127f247372b25e231470517cec272dca659/src/mscorlib/src/System/ValueType.cs#L75):

> Action: Our algorithm for returning the hashcode is a little bit complex.  We look
>   for the first non-static field and get it's hashcode.  If the type has no
>   non-static fields, we return the hashcode of the type.  We can't take the
>   hashcode of a static member because if that member is of the same type as
>   the original type, we'll end up in an infinite loop.

However, the code isn't there, and it looks like that's not *quite* what happens. Sample:

```
using System;

struct Foo
{
    public string x;
    public string y;
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.x = "x";
        foo.y = "y";
        Console.WriteLine(foo.GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine("x".GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine("y".GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Output on my box:

```
42119818
372029398
372029397
```

Changing the value of `y` doesn't appear to change the hash code of `foo`.

However, if we make the fields `int` values instead, then more than the first field affects the output.

In short: this is complex, and you probably shouldn't depend on it remaining the same across multiple versions of the runtime. Unless you're really, really confident that you don't need to use your custom struct as a key in a hash-based dictionary/set, I'd strongly recommend overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` (and implementing `IEquatable<T>` to avoid boxing).

Comment: Using ints shows the value changing so yes, it is complex, but that is also why it is undocumented behavior.

Comment: It seems that when ints are involved (at least) there is a simple XOR of the field gethashcodes/values that is used, if one field = 24, another is 8, the third is 16, then the final result is the same as if I place any other values in there that together XOR to 0.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Ah, I need to correct my answer then - I'd only seen the first field affect things.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Edited. See if you think there's anything else you reckon I should amend.

Comment: No, my comment was only observational and when I discovered that the reference source is not representative I went back to leaning on the documentation, which explicitly *does not* state how this is implemented, only a hand-waving vague description.

Answer (score 1):

The base class of a struct is the `ValueType` class, and the source code is online. They helpfully left a comment that describes how it works:

[ValueType.GetHashCode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/328f227c941517bf.html):

```
/*=================================GetHashCode==================================
**Action: Our algorithm for returning the hashcode is a little bit complex.  We look
**        for the first non-static field and get it's hashcode.  If the type has no
**        non-static fields, we return the hashcode of the type.  We can't take the
**        hashcode of a static member because if that member is of the same type as
**        the original type, we'll end up in an infinite loop.
**Returns: The hashcode for the type.
**Arguments: None.
**Exceptions: None.
==============================================================================*/
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern override int GetHashCode();
```

Comment: I'm assuming he means the base GetHashCode one inherits when a `public struct X` is declared, which is probably one implementation for all.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Oh, of course, thanks! I've updated the answer.