# VB.NET implementation for C# base.GetHashCode() of struct

Tags: c#, vb.net, struct, hashcode

I am porting a C# struct over to VB.NET and am facing the following problem:

The struct is used to safely invoke methods on objects without the need to check for *null* all the time. It has exactly one generic member, which can be *null*:

```
mValue As T
```

The *GetHashCode* method is implemented like that:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    if (this.mValue != null)
    {
        this.mValue.GetHashCode();
    }

    return base.GetHashCode();
}
```

In the VB.NET implementation I cannot do

```
Return MyBase.GetHashCode()
```

because *MyBase* is not valid within a structure.

I have read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009630/10800493) on how *ValueType.GetHashCode* is implemented.

According to this, in my example, I could probably just use

```
Return Me.GetType().GetHashCode()
```

for the case where *mValue* is *null*.

But this does not seem like a very solid implementation to me. Is there some simple way to call *base.GetHashCode()* for a structure in VB.NET?

Comment: What would you expect `base.GetHashCode()` to return anyway? Shouldn't you return the same hash code for every value that has a null value for `mValue`? Why not just return 0?

Comment: You should be able to simply cast the current instance as `ValueType` or `Object`, e.g. `Return DirectCast(Me, ValueType).GetHashCode()`.

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/inheritance-basics

Comment: @jmcilhinney: This will result in a stack overflow because it will call its own *GetHashCode* method indefinitely.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Good question, I did not think about that in much detail. I just wanted the same behaviour as the C# implementation because I have to replace it with my VB.NET implementation of said struct.

Comment: It is not often that vb.net forces you to stop relying on a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927853/17034) :).  That link tells you how to get the C# behavior back, pick the first field in the struct that is non-null and return its GetHashCode() value.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant for the link, that is an interesting read.